# Regex with optional dots in a alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric

I'm trying to write a regex that match a fixed alphanumeric string that may contain dots.
This regex will have to match all the characters but the dots.
I would need to use this in Javascript `search()` for comparing two strings.
Word to find: `30A10Z20`

All of those are a correct match:

```
30A1.0Z2.0
30A.10Z20
3.0.A10.Z20
3.0.A.1.0.Z.2.0.
```

I've written these but with no success:

```
^30A10Z20\\.{0,1}?$
^30A10Z20\\.?$
^30A10Z20(?=\\.)
```

Any leads or help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Would be easier if you just replaced all the dots and then checked whether the string is equal to `30A10Z20`.

Comment: @Sweeper is right, otherwise you'd have to put \.? after every character...

Comment: Is `30A...............10Z20` also valid?

Comment: @georg yes, it is valid

Comment: @Sweeper I thought about that but it's not good for me.
30A10Z20 is just a part of the final string (ex. "30A10Z20 Lorem Ipsum 3324") and I have to match just what I mentioned so I can format it with html tags (bold). It has to contains the dots where they are.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You just check if the string without dots *contains* `30A10Z20` (use `indexOf`), rather than equal to it.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is this:  

(1) Check if word _30A10Z20_ is present in string "3.0A10.Z2.0 Lorem Ipsum 3324"  

(2) Format the resulting part in the string with bold like this "**3.0A10.Z2.0** Lorem Ipsum 3324"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm  not sure a `RegExp` will be the best way to do what I suppose you want to do (based on yur comments: try reformulating your question). Would this snippet be an idea?

```js
const findTerm = (word, searchTerm) => 
  word.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, "") === searchTerm;

const aFewStrings = [
  `something 30A1.0Z2.0 etc`,
  `30A.10Z20 hithere`,
  `Hello 3.0.A10.Z20`,
  `The value 3.0.....A.1.0....Z.2.0. may be valid`,
  `As may be the value 3.0@@@A.1.0#&!'Z.2.0.`,
  `Bye 3.0.A.1.0.Z.2.0. ended`,
];

aFewStrings.forEach(s => {
  const words = s.split(" ").map( w => findTerm(w, "30A10Z20") ? `<b>${w}</b>` : w );
  console.log(words.join(" "));
});
```

If you want parts of the string (cf your comment), you have to do a bit of parsing. Something like:

```js
const findTerm = (word, searchTerm) =>
  RegExp(`(${searchTerm})`, "i").test(word.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, ""));

const toBold = (word, searchTerm) => {
  const word2Parse = [...word];
  const wordPreserved = word2Parse.slice(0);
  const len = searchTerm.length;
  let foundIndices = [];
  let i = 0;

  while (word2Parse.length) {
    const noDots = word2Parse.slice(1).filter(v => !/[^a-z0-9]/i.test(v));
    const next = searchTerm.length > 1 &&  noDots[0] === searchTerm[1];
    const found = searchTerm.length > 1 
        ? word2Parse[0] === searchTerm[0] && next
        : word2Parse[0] === searchTerm[0];
    
    searchTerm = found ? searchTerm.slice(1) : searchTerm;
    found && foundIndices.push(i);
    i += 1;
    word2Parse.shift();
  }


  wordPreserved[foundIndices[0]] = `<b>${wordPreserved[foundIndices[0]]}`;
  wordPreserved[foundIndices.slice(-1)] = `${
        wordPreserved[foundIndices.slice(-1)]}</b>`;
  return wordPreserved.join("");
}

const aFewStrings = [
  `something 30A1.0Z2.0 etc`,
  `30A.10Z20 hithere`,
  `Hello 3.0.A10.Z20`,
  `The value 3.0.....A.1.0....Z.2.0. may be valid`,
  `As may be the value 3.0@@@A.1.0#&!'Z.2.0.`,
  `Bye 3.0.A.1.0.Z.2.0. ended`,
  `3.0.A.1.0.Z.2.....0`,
];


const result = document.querySelector("#result");

let term = `30A1`;
result.appendChild(
  Object.assign(
    document.createElement("p"), {
      innerHTML: `[1 String, search '30A1']: ${
          (aFewStrings[3].split(" ")
            .map(w =>
                findTerm(w, term) ? toBold(w, term) : w)
            .join(" "))}`
    })
);

term = `notfound`;
result.appendChild(
  Object.assign(
    document.createElement("p"), {
      innerHTML: `[1 String, search 'notfound']: ${
          (aFewStrings[1].split(" ")
            .map(w =>
                findTerm(w, term) ? toBold(w, term) : w)
            .join(" "))}`
    })
);

term = `0Z20`;
aFewStrings.forEach(s => {
  const words = s.split(" ").map(w =>
    findTerm(w, term) ? toBold(w, term) : w);
  result.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
      document.createElement("div"), {
        innerHTML: words.join(" ")
      })
  );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This is working, very nice. But is there a way to make it work just with a part of the string?   
 e.g. "30A1" --> <b>30.A1</b>0Z.20 or "Z20" --> 30.A.10<b>Z20</b>

Comment: I suppose it can be done, but it's really more complex. You may want to consider simplifying the input (so, make sure the dots are not there in the first place)

Comment: I can remove the dots on the input and make the comparison. But later I need a way to put the text format bold on just what I have found in the first place.